# How to apeend data to a file in node js

Tags: xml, node.js, tags, rss

I want my xml file to be in this way

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
          <item>
             <title>hi</title>
             <link>https://www.hi.com</link>
         </item>

         <item>
              <title>hello</title>
              <link>https://www.hello.com</link>
            </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

But i am getting  in  this  way,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>hi</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>JJJJJJJ@@@</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Here rss ,xml tags are repeating because of the following code,

```
 var blog = {blog_id:"experts-personalized-med",title:"JJJJJJJ@@@"}
    var obj = {rss:{channel:{title:"xpertdox",link:"http://localhost:4000",description:"Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease",item:{title: blog.title, link: "https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/"+blog.blog_id}}}};
            var fs = require('fs');
            var xml2js = require('xml2js');
            var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
            var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
            console.log(xml);  
                fs.appendFile('public/feed.xml', xml, function (err){
                if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('It\'s saved!');
                });
```

Here in my code the tags are repeated whenever a new object is entered.This is my situation,can anyone help me to get the desired shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <rss>
      <channel>
        <title>xpertdox</title>
        <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
        <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
           ------------------------------------------
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

This is how my file should be at initial and the new objects should come in between when i append it.

This was showed in my  console

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>JJJJJJJ@@@</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

THis is my file after inserting 2 records

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>JJJJJJJ@@@</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>JJJJJJJ@@@</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>xpertdox</title>
    <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
    <description>Find an xpert doctor for a rare disease</description>
    <item>
      <title>JJJJJJJ@@@</title>
      <link>https://www.xpertdox.com/blog/blog-description/experts-personalized-med</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Seems you're appending on your xml file as `fs.appendFile('public/feed.xml, xml,.....` instead of writing the same as `fs.writeFile(.......`

Comment: Not that my question is how to append data in between a file

Comment: At particular locations.....put curser at required point

Comment: Do you mean to say, the `</rss><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><rss>` which are getting appended in between of your XML content should not be coming?

Comment: Please see my  editted code at bottom

Comment: Got it!. What do you get you do a console.log of your `xml` variable (`var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);`)

Comment: pls see my edited code nw